# Viewpager scrolling finish event

Tags: android

I have a viewpager that dislapys text views.  I have header layout above it.  What i want is to hide or display this header when the user click on the screen.  but not when the scrolling is occur. I tried the ViewPager.onPageChangeListener.  But with no success.  What i need is how to know when the swapping between pages finishes. The onPageScrollStateChange didnt help i create an instance variable to hold the state and keep updating it when this method call so i can use it in my onclick listener to now if the page is scrolling or not but with no success

Comment: I'm inclined to say that `onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)` in combination with `SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING` should do the job. It sounds more like you're having trouble actually implementing it. If that's the case, you should probably show us some of the code you've written.

Answer (score 9):

```
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            if(ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE == state){
                //Scrolling finished. Do something.
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi @Vladimir Petrovski, i implemented viewpager with video but when i scroll fast then previous video sound coming on new scrolled video, so what i need to do for stop previous music on new view?